# assert_valid_keys in form view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm brand new to programming and even newer to ROR.  I'm having a problem with the forms of one of my pages.  I used javascript to create a drop down menu that changes a lower drop down menu (for example if you choose a state, the drop down menu below will only display cities from that state instead of all of the cities on the table it's linked to).  My drop-down menus are sectors and subsectors.  After doing that, I get this error for the line of code I made.

```
Undefined Method 'assert_valid_keys' for :company:symbol
```

I'm not sure what this is trying to tell me and after looking around on the internet for a while with no success I decided to ask here.

It says the error occurs on line 30 (second line in excerpt).  This is in the form.html for the company table.

```
<%= f.label :subsector_id %><br />
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :subsector_id, Sector.all, :subsectors, :sector_name, :id, :subsector_name %>
```

These are the models for the tables.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :sector
has_many :subsectors, through: :sectors
attr_accessible :city, :company_name, :description, :employees,
:sector_id, :subsector_attributes, :subsector_id
end

class Subsector < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :sector_id, :subsector_name, :subsector_id
belongs_to :sector, :company
end

class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :sector_name
has_many :companies
has_many :subsectors
end
```

Here is the Controller for subsectors.

```
class SubsectorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subsectors = Subsector.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @subsectors }
    end
end

  def show
    @subsector = Subsector.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @subsector }
end
end

  def new
    @subsector = Subsector.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @subsector }
end 
end

  def edit
    @subsector = Subsector.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @subsector = Subsector.new(params[:subsector])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subsector.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subsector, notice: 'Subsector was successfully
created.' }
        format.json { render json: @subsector, status: :created, location: @subsector }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @subsector.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end 
end
end
```

The same error also occurs when I try to open the subsectors page.  I'm not sure where I need to look to fix this.

If anyone could just let me know where I should look to try to figure this one out.  Or give me a general idea of why errors like these come up that would be great!

Comment: could you share a little more of your code? Kinda hard to tell where 'company' is coming from. There is probably an issue with the "grouped_collection_select" method call you are making. Check out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select and make sure the parameters (:subsector_id, Sector.all etc) are correct.

Comment: I put some more code up.  Let me know if I should put more.